# Undertow close connection

Tags: java, undertow

I've server on Undertow and all was perfect until I've meet client who doesn't close connections, so server should do it. But undertow doesn't do it and that's why with some time my server runs out of file descriptors permitted by the system. I've tried to find any code related to channel closing in undertow, but I can't. I found only close in `HttpServerExchange.endExchange()` for blocking http exchange and solution with `UndertowOptions.IDLE_TIMEOUT` but they doesn't suite me. So how and when does undertow close channels ?

My undertow version is 1.2.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found an answer. `HttpServerExchange.setPersistent(false)` resolved it.

Comment: Hi Alexander. What it exactly does?